# glibc on alpine aarch64: gcompat: no such package

Tags: package, alpine-linux, libc

I follow [official Alpine Linux guide](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs) on aarch64 vm (installed from alpine-virt-...iso) but i can't find `gcompat` package:

```
myvm:~# apk add gcompat
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  gcompat (no such package):
    required by: world[gcompat]
```

How can i do it?

Comment: What's your version of Alpine? It is available at least since 3.8. (`cat /etc/os-release`)

Comment: Also, try to run it with the `--no-cache`, in order to bypass package repository not up-to-date issues.

Comment: I've tried with 3.14

Comment: `--no-cache` did not help, same output

Comment: tested on x86_84 - same story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment `#http://mirror.reenigne.net/alpine/v3.14/community` in `/etc/apk/repositories` and retry